# Why is onClickListener not working in my ViewPager Frament

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

So basically I have a viewpager whose fragments are added and removed dynamically. What I am trying to do is set onClick function in fragment and do something related to that fragment.
Following is my code.

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String ARG_LAYOUT="layout";
private QuoteData quoteData;
private String textTospeak;
private Speaker speaker;
//Returns an Instance of fragment
static Fragment newInstance(int layoutId, QuoteData quoteData) {
    Fragment result=new MainFragment();
    //quoteData = quoteDat;
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT, layoutId);
    args.putString("quote", quoteData.getQuote());
    args.putString("author", quoteData.getAuthorName());
    args.putString("imgurl", quoteData.getAuthorName());
    result.setArguments(args);
    return(result);
}

public MainFragment(){}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt(ARG_LAYOUT),container, false);
    TextView textview = (TextView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.quotetext);
    String text = (String)getArguments().get("quote") +"\n\t\t\t"+getArguments().get("author");
    textview.setText(text);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.speak);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return(fragmentView);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //speak();
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Show me something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

}

Then I used the OnClick attribute in Fragment's xml and created a function in my MainActivity, which didn't work either.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: try calling .show() on the toast, it would be funny if that was it - also put a log statement in there too

Comment: @SaikCaskey hahaha yeah that was it! It made me feel really stupid lol

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //speak();
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Show me something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

With:

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //speak();
           if(v.getId() == imageButton.getId()){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Show me something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
```